# python- construction of lattice which traps molecules - doesn't work right

Tags: python, scipy, random-walk

I have this problem :

> Create a program which constructs a lattice of one (1) dimension and
>   100000 sites. In this lattice put at random positions a number of trap
>   molecules, which will have concentration c. Put 1 particle in a random
>   position on the lattice and let it perform a random walk. In this walk
>   you will not place a time restriction, namely you will not declare a
>   specific number of steps. The walk will stop when the particle falls
>   on a trap.............................. ...Beware of boundary
>   conditions. When the particle reaches the borders of the lattice it
>   shouldn’t be allowed to escape from it but to remain in the lattice,
>   either by returning on it former position or by being placed in the
>   opposite site of the lattice........

My approach is shown in the code i created (i have comments in it).

```
def steps1d(self,pos,c):
    #pos: number of positions
    #c:   concentration of trap-particles

    # array full of traps (zeros)
    myzeros = sc.zeros(self.c*self.pos)

    # grid full of available positions(ones)
    grid = sc.ones(self.pos)

    # distribute c*pos zeros(traps) in random positions (number of positions is pos)
    traps = sc.random.permutation(pos)[:c*pos]

    # the grid in which the particle is moving which has traps inside it 
    grid[traps] = myzeros
    steps_count = []    # list which holds the number of steps
    free = 0
    for i in range(pos):
        # the step of the particle can be 0 or 1
        step=sc.random.random_integers(0,1)
        for step in grid[:]:
            if step == 1:
                free += 1
                steps_count.append(free)
            else:
                break
    return steps_count
```

I have 3 problems :

1) The results i am taking for example for pos=10 are sth like:

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35...]

I would expect 10 numbers each for 1 run (variable pos).

2) I am not sure how to handle the boundary conditions. I am thinking something like:

```
if free > grid.size:
    free = free - 1
```

But I can't test it. Also,i am not sure if this applies for both borders of the grid.

3) If i want the first step to begin from the middle of the grid, how can I do it?

If someone has a hint on that, I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a smaller lattice, to see what is happening:

```
import numpy

# Populate the lattice
lattice = numpy.concatenate([numpy.ones(90), numpy.zeros(10)])
numpy.random.shuffle(lattice)

# Intialize problem
in_trap = False
steps = 0
pos = int(numpy.random.randint(0,len(lattice),1))
history = []

while in_trap == False:
    # Step of -1 is backward, 1 is forward
    step = numpy.random.permutation([-1,1])[0]

    # Check position for edges and fix if required
    if pos + step > len(lattice) - 1:
        pos = 0
    elif pos + step < 0:
        pos = len(lattice) - 1
    else:
        pos += step

    # Keep track of random walk
    history.append(pos)

    # Check if it's a trap
    if lattice[pos] == 0:
        in_trap = True

    # If not, continue
    steps += 1


print steps
print history
print lattice
```

I would encourage you to thrown in print statements throughout to see what values each variable is holding. Trying it out on smaller lattices will help you understand how this works.

EDIT:

I'm going to let you figure out the specifics, but I would wrap this in a function like follows. It sets up the function, then prepares empty steps and histories lists to hold the results of each run. We run the function, then append the results to those lists.

```
def lattice():
    code
    return steps, history

steps = []
histories = []
for i in range(0,10):
    num_steps, history = lattice()
    steps.append(num_steps)
    histories.append(history)
```

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for the help!I have a few questions though.1)You are appending the position (pos) to the history ,which just holds the different positions where the particle goes.But i want the number of the steps the particle does until it finds a trap.I want the steps to be appended,right?Also,i didn't understand the "elif pos+step<0"statement.

Comment: OK,ok,ok!I got it!Ok,it was a little hard for me,but i got it now!Thanks!

Comment: :Hello,i am having a difficulty in the part that does the run.For example , i have to run the above 10 times.So, i am putting the while statement into a for loop. for i in range(10).And i am expecting to take 10 different steps.But i am taking only one step!I am trying this from yesterday but i can't make it work!!

Comment: :Also,i think in the elif statement it should be: pos=len(lattice)-1 and not len(lattice-1) ,is that right?

Comment: Thanks, fixed the error. If you only put the while loop in your for loop, you are not resetting the problem. You need to put also the lines in "Initializing the problem".

Comment: :Ok,thanks ,it works but i have 2 problems! 1) For 10 runs it gives me 11 values of steps from which the last it is value None.  2) Because i am putting it in a function when i use return it returns me only one value!(I use steps_count=[] and then after the steps+=1 i do steps_count.append(steps) in order to return the steps_count list.Sorry for this but i am really working on it!

Comment: No need to apologize, I'm glad you're working on it! See edits for help with wrapping in a function.

Comment: :Thank you very much.I had an indent error(logic) ,that's why i couldn't have a list full of steps!Now its ok.Thanks again

Comment: :I wanted to ask sth last :) (if you don't have time i understand).I am trying to do it in a 2dimensional grid.I am updating my post.I tried sth but it doesn't work.

Comment: You should post your 2-d question in a new question, and remove the edit. Link the new question to this one to show you reasoning. This is getting to be a lot of new material for the same question.

Answer (score 0):

The part where the grid is created is OK (although you used `traps` twice - I suppose you don't need the 1st line and the 4th line should be `grid[traps]=0`).

Then according to the problem you have to put a molecule and make it walk on the grid, and this part of your program is completely wrong. What you need to do is find a random starting point for the molecule (with `sc.random.randint(pos)` maybe), and then count the number of steps the molecule makes before falling in a trap. Steps in 1d random walk can be either to the left (`starting_point - 1`) or to the right (`starting_point + 1`). You have to choose randomly between `[-1, +1]`, add the step to the index of the molecule on the grid and if the resultant index appears to be free on the grid then increment your `free` variable. If the resultant index hits the trap, then append the `free` variable to the `steps_count` list.

To answer your second question, periodic boundary conditions can be applied seamlessly to the grid if you take the remainder of `index % pos` division as the index of the molecule.